# RecyclerView onClick for multiple buttons and handling from Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, buttonclick

I'm using `RecyclerView` with `CardView` and inside the `CardView` have 2 buttons. Now, have implemented the `onClick` events by implementing `View.OnClickListener` by the `ViewHolder` static class and overriding the event (its working )like

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == mClassBtn.getId()){

        }
        else if (v.getId() == mDaysBtn.getId()){

        }
     }
```

Looking for a solution/pattern to handle the `Click` in the `Activity` class like

```
adapter = new ItemsListAdapter(getActivity(), data, new CustomItemClickListener() { 

    @override
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {

       Log.d(TAG, "clicked position:" + position);
       // which button clicked and separate action for each button
    } 
});
// CustomItemClickListener -- interface in the adapter class which holds the click event .
```

The above code working fine and able to log the `Clicks` but not able to differentiate which button has clicked.

Appreciate any help

Comment: You can use setTag and getTag, when you define your buttons set tag for first as 1 and other 2, and then you can differentiate by calling v.getTag()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

here is the best way to achieve that:--

this is how i have implemented

```
public class FollowersDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FollowersDetailsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<GetUserFollowDetailsResponseData> followersList;
    Context context;
    public FollowersDetailsAdapterListener onClickListener;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView rv_tv_follower_name, rv_tv_follower_desig;
        public CircleImageView rv_iv_follower_image;
        RelativeLayout rv_rel_layout_followers, rel_layout_followers;
        LikeButton rv_iv_follower_icon;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            rv_rel_layout_followers = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_rel_layout_followers);
            rel_layout_followers = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rel_layout_followers);
            rv_iv_follower_image = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_iv_follower_image);
            rv_tv_follower_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_tv_follower_name);
            rv_tv_follower_desig = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_tv_follower_desig);
            rv_iv_follower_icon = (LikeButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_iv_follower_icon);
            rel_layout_followers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onClickListener.iconTextViewOnClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public FollowersDetailsAdapter(List<GetUserFollowDetailsResponseData> FollowersList, FollowersDetailsAdapterListener listener) {
        this.followersList = FollowersList;
        this.onClickListener = listener;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.followers_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (followersList.get(position).getImage() != null && !followersList.get(position).getImage().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Picasso.with(context)

                    .load(followersList.get(position).getImage())
                    .resize(200, 200).into(holder.rv_iv_follower_image);
        }

        holder.rv_tv_follower_name.setText(followersList.get(position).getName());
        holder.rv_tv_follower_desig.setText(followersList.get(position).getDescription());
        if (followersList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getID() == Integer.parseInt(ApplicationPreference.getUserId())) {
            holder.rv_iv_follower_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.rv_iv_follower_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (followersList.get(position).getIsFollowing() == 0) {
                holder.rv_iv_follower_icon.setLiked(false);
            } else if (followersList.get(position).getIsFollowing() == 1) {
                holder.rv_iv_follower_icon.setLiked(true);
            }


        }
        holder.rv_iv_follower_icon.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
            @Override
            public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {

                onClickListener.iconImageViewOnClick(likeButton, position);
            }

            @Override
            public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {
                onClickListener.iconImageUnFollowOnClick(likeButton, position);
            }
        });

    }

    public interface FollowersDetailsAdapterListener {

        void iconTextViewOnClick(View v, int position);

        void iconImageViewOnClick(View v, int position);

        void iconImageUnFollowOnClick(View v, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return followersList.size();
    }
}
```

and in your activity where you initialize the adapter--

```
 followersDetailsAdapter = new FollowersDetailsAdapter(followersList, new FollowersDetailsAdapter.FollowersDetailsAdapterListener() {
            @Override
            public void iconTextViewOnClick(View v, int position) {
                gotoUserProfile(followersList.get(position).getID());

            }

            @Override
            public void iconImageViewOnClick(View v, int position) {

                followUserProfile(followersList.get(position).getID(),1);
            }

            @Override
            public void iconImageUnFollowOnClick(View v, int position){

                followUserProfile(followersList.get(position).getID(),0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: this is what I tried previously. But I have 2 buttons in the Recyclerview Item View and need to handle the onClicks separately rather than onItemClick for the view itself

Comment: this is a similar application i have used earlier, you can take reference from this

Comment: Thanks alot .. I will try it and will let you know

Comment: instead of the onLikeListener, you can use onClickListeners, happy to help :)

Comment: can we make it as view or button instead of relativelayout?  rel_layout_followers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onClickListener.iconTextViewOnClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

Comment: yeah you can use a button instead

Comment: for both the buttons separately?

Comment: yeah, see i have used 3 listeners in the interface, you can use them for your buttons

Comment: One more question please , is there any performance issue if we are not using Viewholder class as "static". Since to refer the listener inside the constructor of ViewHolder it requires to be non static class

Answer (score 10):

Please, try this principle to create a communication between activity, adapter through the interface, I hope this principle helps you:

**Model Class:**

```
public class YourModel {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public YourModel(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //... setters & getters
}
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface AdapterCallback {
    void onClickCallback(YourModel itemModel);
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<YourModel> data;
    private AdapterCallback callback;
    private Context context;

    public YourAdapter(List<YourModel> data, AdapterCallback callback) {
        this.data = data;
        this.callback = callback
    }

    @Override
    public YourAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recycler, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(YourAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        YourModel itemModel = data.get(position);

        String lastName  = itemModel.getLastName();  
        String firstName = itemModel.getFirstName();

        holder.tvFirstName.setText(firstName);
        holder.tvLastName.setText(lastName);

        holder.tvFirstName.setOnClickListener { 
           callback.onClickCallback(itemModel));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvFirstName;
        private TextView tvLastName;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFirstName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_first);
            tvLastName  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_last);
        }

}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterCallback {

private YourAdapter adapter;
private List<YourModel> items;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // 1. init your list && fill it with needed data
    // 2. init your adapter 
    // 3. put your list as parameter into constructor + interface
    items = new ArrayList<YourModel>()
    items.add(YourModel("John", "Doe"));
    items.add(YourModel("Bob", "Marley"));
    adapter = new YourAdapter(items, this)
}

@Override
public void onClickCallback(YourModel itemModel) {
    Toast.makeText(this, itemModel.getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I think that this information is enough to understand what I mean.
The same principle you can create multiple OnClick methods in your interface or put one onClick for a few buttons and check id or something else to get needed information that you need. **Good luck**

Comment: Hey I was just wondering why your activity implements View.OnClickListener? Is this required to implement the AdapterCallback interface?

Comment: @Burkely91 Hey, oops, I think it's my mistake, i just forgot to remove it :)

Comment: your method looks good, but it's not working. Error says that  setonclicklistener cannot be applied to view (void)

Comment: @IvanVovk If it's still actual I can send you example project with implemented code

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution if it could help someone.

You could click in one item of the recyclerview or one of the two buttons.

The interface implements:

onStudentItemClick, for click in the recyclerview item

onChatItemClick and onAbsenceItemClick for click the buttons

With

```
 holder.imgChat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mOnClickListener.onChatItemClick(mStudents.get(index));

                }
            });
```

I set the click listener for one button

And in the class StudentViewHolder I implement OnClickListener and override onClik

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mOnClickListener != null){
                int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                mOnClickListener.onStudentItemClick(mStudents.get(clickedPosition));
            }
        }
```

Here the Adapter:

```
public class StudentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentsAdapter.StudentsViewHolder> {

    private ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
    private ArrayList<Student> mStudents;

    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        void onStudentItemClick(Student student);
        void onChatItemClick(Student student);
        void onAbsenceItemClick(Student student);
    }


    public StudentsAdapter(ArrayList<Student> students, ListItemClickListener listener) {
        mStudents = students;
        mOnClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public StudentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.student_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        StudentsViewHolder viewHolder = new StudentsViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StudentsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Integer index = position;
        holder.tvStudent.setText(mStudents.get(position).nameForList());
        holder.imgChat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mOnClickListener.onChatItemClick(mStudents.get(index));

            }
        });
        holder.imgAbsence.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mOnClickListener.onAbsenceItemClick(mStudents.get(index));

            }
        });

    }

    public Student getItem(Integer position){
        return mStudents.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mStudents.size();
    }


    class StudentsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements OnClickListener {

        ImageView imgStudent;
        TextView tvStudent;
        ImageButton imgChat, imgAbsence;

        public StudentsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imgStudent = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_student);
            tvStudent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_student);
            imgChat = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_chat_student);
            imgAbsence = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_absence);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mOnClickListener != null){
                int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                mOnClickListener.onStudentItemClick(mStudents.get(clickedPosition));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment the implement the interface:

```
public class SubjectDetailFragment extends Fragment implements  StudentsAdapter.ListItemClickListener {
...
@Override
public void onStudentItemClick(Student student) {
    StudentDetailFragment detailFragment = StudentDetailFragment.newInstance();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("student", student);
    detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, detailFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

@Override
public void onChatItemClick(Student student) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void onAbsenceItemClick(Student student) {
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your activity do like this

```
CustomItemClickListener listner;

listner=YourActivityName.this   // in OnCreate Method
```

and pass this listner in your adapter

```
adapter = new ItemsListAdapter(getActivity(), data, listner);
```

And in your Adapter use it like this

```
CustomItemClickListener listner;

this.listner=listner; // In your Adapter COnstructor
```

and last in your onBindViewHolder do like this

```
holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listner.onItemClick(holder.getLayoutPosition()); //getting position
            }
        });

holder.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listner.onItemClick(holder.getLayoutPosition()); //getting position
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

I do it this way.

1. Set an OnClickListener on your Button in the ViewHolder
2. Create a method in your activity with the button position as a parameter
3. Pass the position of the clicked entry and do stuff

ViewHolder

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {

        int position = getAdapterPosition(); //Clicked entry in your List

        //Method from your activity
        yourActivity.methodOnBtnClick(position);
     }
```

Activity

```
public void methodOnBtnClick(int position)
{
    yourList.remove(position);
    recycler.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```